# Move pieces on the board at random chess programming

Tags: java

I am creating a chess program whereby computer plays against human, but for now I just simply want the computer to move pieces on the board at random after I have moved a piece as human. Everything seems to be working fine, but computer won't move piece on the board except I click the file menu which the click command for action performed is initiated. So I have to always click before computer moves piece at random on the board. But I want it to be "automatic".

I am doing it like this;

```
if (command == "1") {
    while(!gameover) {
        if (board.getTurn()) {  //computer turn
            List<Map.Entry<Location, ArrayList<Location>>> whitemovelist = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Location, ArrayList<Location>>>(whitemap.entrySet());
            Collections.shuffle(whitemovelist);
            System.out.println("White turn");
            for (Map.Entry<Location, ArrayList<Location>> entry : whitemovelist) {
                if(entry.getValue().size() != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " :: " + entry.getValue().get(i));
                        from = entry.getKey();
                        to = entry.getValue().get(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            processOne(from);
            movePiece(to);
            System.out.println("Take piece " +board.takenPiece);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want people to volunteer their time for free to help you solve your problems, at least take the time to format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious after you read it.

1. Remove the code from the file menu click event.
2. Move your code into a method, eg: `AIMovePiece()`
3. Call the method after you have performed the human players turn.